Largest Tetrahedra from a set of points
Problem

Given a set of k points in 3D Euclidean space with k ≥ 4, find four points from the set that form a tetrahedra such that the volume of the tetrahedra is maximized.

Attempted Solution

Find the points that have the minimum and maximum x-values of the set, the minimum and maximum y-values of the set, and the minimum and maximum z-values of the set
Take the pair of points from that set that has the largest distance from each other forming a line
Take the point that is furthest from the line, forming a plane
Take the point that is furthest from the plane, forming a tetrahedron from the 4 points

Questions

Is this algorithm correct? Or is there a counter example one can find? My gut feeling says that there should be a counter example for some nearly coplanar points, but I am still looking
If the algorithm is correct, is there an algorithm other than this one with a better complexity? I believe the complexity of the algorithm above is O(n) as step 1 loops through all points in O(n) doing compares; step 2 is O(1) as it only looks at most 6 points and does compares; step 3 is O(n) as it loops through all points computing the distance in O(1) and then doing a compare; and step 4 is also O(n) for the same reason as step 3


I suggest you implement your algorithm and some known-correct reference algorithm (e.g., iterating over all subsets of 4 vertices), generate a million random test cases (with a small number of points), and check whether your algorithm always gives the right answer on each of those test cases.  You could also test one million test cases generated from a special distribution (e.g., nearly coplanar).  That would be a good first step, which might either surface some counterexamples or give you more confidence in your algorithm.

I found a counter example with a set of 8 points:
Point1: (73.035820, 89.248856, 4.658190)
Point2: (0.000000, 132.029068, -28.621250)
Point3: (-3.660427, 144.880646, 24.171749)
Point4: (-19.928558, 0.819754,13.723690)
Point5: (13.250628, 0.819646, 23.758114)
Point6: (0.000000, 154.288559, -11.281099)
Point7: (-73.035820, 89.248856, 4.658190)
Point8: (1.186876, 144.880646, 24.171749)
I am going to try to make modifications to get a correct algorithm as the O(n^4) brute force takes a long time to run on big sets

I tried a couple of things that did not work. I replaced step 4 with pick the point that has the largest volume, but that still returned a tetrahedra with a smaller volume than the brute force. I tried replacing step 3 with furthest distance from the line segment instead of line, but that didn't work. I tried replacing steps 3 and 4 together, but it still didn't work. I am going to try to replace step 2 next with looping over all pairs of extremal points to see if that makes a difference.

A little more progress, I tried looping over all pairs of extremal points, and for each pair, find the point furthest from the line through the pair and the point furthest from the line segment, and then pick the fourth point that maximizes volume. However, using the line or the line segment fails. One curious thing, I haven't tried many examples yet, but it seems that almost always a pair of extremal points (points on the axis-aligned bounding box) appear in the largest volume tetrahedra

I believe I found a set of 10 points that only one extremal point is part of the largest volume tetrahedra: (-25.614927, 0.786838, 9.162713) (63.981224, 41.389809, 88.810562), (-16.841095, -76.088676, 85.136238), (56.961437, 48.309967, 84.746429), (2.116667, -9.650833, -1.774758), (48.012154, -22.705223, 144.808685), (61.659313, -39.880821, 113.395325), (25.992296, -12.452285, 144.074341), (0.286482, 23.548450, 5.616717), and (-19.318573, -63.963295, 87.324738). Still looking to see if there is a case where no points of the largest volume tetrahedra are on the Axis-Aligned Bounding Box (AABB).
